# Can we open shared drive on client machine using java web application?

Tags: java, spring, web

My java web application is deployed on server machine. I have a share drive which is accessible from client machine as well as server machine . Using below code i am able to open that drive on server machine :

Spring Controller code :

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/openAttachment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ResponseEntity<List<String>> 
      OpenFolder(@RequestParam("workflowName") String workflowName  ) throws 
      IOException, InterruptedException {
         String folderPath =Constants.workFlowAttachPath+workflowName;       
        if ((new File(folderPath)).exists()) {
            Process p = Runtime
               .getRuntime()
               .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+folderPath);
               p.waitFor();

         }
            List<String> msgList = new ArrayList<> ();
           msgList.add(Constants.SUCCESSFUL);
          return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(msgList, HttpStatus.OK);
         }
```

Constant used here is :

```
public static final String workFlowAttachPath="\\\\10.82.31.27\\Area20\\Attachment\\";
```

But i am unable to open this folder from local machine(browser) on local machine . 
Is this possible ? If possible then how ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. If you're okay with hardcoding windows and system state into your code, you can mount that folder on a drive letter, say, drive 'N:', and then use path:

```
psf String workFlowAttachPath = "N:\\Attachment\\";
```

you can mount this on windows with something like:

```
net use N: \\\\10.82.31.27\\Area20 /PERSISTENT:YES
```

but I'm just going off of memory on that one so you'd have to check the docs on the `net use` windows command for the details. You should be able to invoke 'net.exe' via Runtime.getRuntime().exec() but I advise against that. You're already hardcoding IPs and who knows what in this code, might as well take care of mounting the N: drive externally too. This avoids having to deal with errors from the net command from within your java code, which is notoriously hard; windows likes to translate its commands and can throw quite a few weird errors, writing code to invoke windows utilities from java and understand their outputs is a non-trivial job.